# How to change default path of a user in Unix?

Tags: linux

How can we change the default path of a user in the Unix?
Suppose i have created the user Rookie.The default path of this user as shown in /etc/passwd file is /home/Rookie.
Can i change the default path of this user to /home/Rookie/release/logs?

Comment: That `/home/Rookie` entry you see in `/etc/passwd` is called the user's *home directory*.

Answer (score 2):

use usermod

example:

```
usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/dir userNameHere
```

Answer (score 2):

`usermod -m -d /path/to/new/login/home/dir  user`

This shall change existing user home directory to a new login directory. option -m moves the contents of the current home directory to the new home dir

for more information issue `man usermod`

hope this help!

UPDATE 1:

Also see the link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-default-home-directory/ for better explanation.